# How to resolve the 100% disk usage on my iMac 27" (late 2013) when in Bootcamp bootup

Tags: imac, bootcamp, startup, windows, dual-boot

I own an iMac from the late 2013 series, it is the core i7 with 32GB RAM. I eventually established that using Bootcamp would allow for a better experience when working in Windows land (I am both an iOS developer and a C# developer).

However, on booting to Windows the hard drive in resource management (listed as an APPLE HDD WDC WD10EALX-408EA0) goes into 100% usage for around 10 minutes before the computer is responsive to use. This is without loading additional applications, just loading into windows in the first place.

After the system has loaded, it is fast and responsive (i.e. no additional paging or anything). Does anyone know what the resolution for this is?

[image]

Comment: Did it always do this from the first time you installed Windows or did this start later on?  How much free space do you have on the volume Windows is installed?

Comment: Hello, yes it has done this from the very first installation. I have around 27GB of free space on bootcamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my particular problem is to be found [here](http://techat-jack.blogspot.nl/2012/09/solved-high-cpu-usage-of-microsoft.html) which suggests excluding the process MsMpEng.exe from the windows defender service. I'm running windows 8.1 so this done by searching for Windows Defender in your programs, clicking on the settings tab (far right) and then browsing to 'C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MsMpEng.exe' and adding it to the excluded files and locations. Disk usage reduces drammatically!

Answer (score 0):

i think you should increase virtual memory and unnecessary services which will solved your 100% disk usages problem try this video step by step
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nzK9x_iV6M8 
i hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  While the link you provided may answer the question, it's advisable to summarize and/or provide the relevant details that answer the question here.  Links often go stale making the answer useless.

Comment: sorry i am new please guide me we cant post video links? 
 i have same issue which resolved with this video tutorial this is very helpful video

Comment: It's ok to post a link, but we prefer to have answers stand on their own. So if the video contains information relevant for the topic, please summarize it directly into your answer. This will make your answer more valuable and also protect it against link rot (in the current form, the answer will become useless if the video gets removed from YouTube).